# Rewrite rule Mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Please help. How can I get this

`http://example.com/search/1961/1/xxx`

from this

`http://example.com/search?year=1961&category_id=1?title=xxx`

The request may be missing some of the parameters. For example:

`http://example.com/search?year=1961&category_id=1`

or

`http://example.com/search?title=xxx`

Comment: So what have you tried yourself? Where are you stuck? We are not here to do your work for you. We are here to help solving issues with _your_ code. note that there are millions of examples for what you ask. So you should be able to start yourself. Then, if you run into an issue you cannot solve yourself after consulting the documentation, _then_ is the time to ask here about that specific issue.